# Using Diff() in R for multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, diff

I would like to calculate the first order difference for many columns in a data frame without naming them explicitly. It works well with one column with this code:

```
set.seed(1)
Data <- data.frame(
  X = sample(1:10),
  Y = sample(1:10),
  Z = sample(1:10))
 Newdata <- as.data.frame(diff(Data$X, lag = 1))
```

How to I calculate the same for a lot of columns, e.g.[2:200], in a data frame?

Comment: `Newdata[2:200] <- NA ; Newdata[2:200] <- lapply(Data[2:200], diff)`?

Comment: @r2evans: Yes. Works. Thanks. Solution of BrodieG is even more easy and versatile.

Comment: No worries. You specified a range of columns, I worked on that range of columns. Had you mentioned that it was certainly "all columns", that works just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(Data, diff, lag=1))
##    X  Y  Z
## 1  1 -1 -8
## 2  1  4  4
## 3  2  4 -5
## 4 -5 -5  8
## 5  6  2 -1
## 6  1  1 -1
## 7 -3 -4 -2
## 8  4 -3 -2
## 9 -9  8  1
```

Since data frames are internally lists, we can `lapply` over the columns.  You can use `Data[1:2]` instead of `Data` to just do the first two columns, or any valid column indexing.